# Is there a way to have a dictionary of lists of labels in Bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I'm trying to create set of rules in [Bazel](https://www.bazel.build/) for a tool my company works with.
Is there any way to create a rule attribute which is a dict of lists of labels, where the key for the dict is a string?

For example, a target should look like this:

```
some_rule (
    name = "target_name",
    files = {
        "foo" : [
            "file1",
            "file2",
        ],
        "bar" : [
            "file3",
            "file4",
            "file5"
        ]
    }
)
```

*Note:* I know i could distinguish between `foo` and `bar` by having them in separate targets and then having a third one to depend on both, but would rather that they all be in the same target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. This feature request is [tracked here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7989).